# jQuery input click event before onbeforeunload?

Tags: jquery, click, onbeforeunload

I would like to have my business logic in my onbeforeunload event handler only occur when a specified element was clicked.

I have the following code (simplified):

```
var myButtonClicked = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = myEventHandler;
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    myButtonClicked = true;

    $("#myform").submit();
  });
});

function myEventHandler(event)
{
  if (myButtonClicked)
  {
    // Do checking.
    // return "Dirty flag..blahblah";
  }
}
```

Currently this is producing quite bizarre behaviour - the first time my button is clicked, the click event is handled after the myEventHandler.  The second time I click it, it is handled beforehand (this is in FF4.0).

Any help on getting this working would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed. :)

Basically I had two click events;

```
myButton.click(function() {
  ...
  ignoreFlag = true;
});

myButton.click(function() {
  form.submit();
});
```

It was always a contest as to which event was fired first.  I merged the two and it appears to be working correctly.

Thanks for your help ysrb :)

Comment: Have you tried putting return false;?

$("#myButton").click(function() {
    myButtonClicked = true;
return false;
  });

My guess it's posting back.

Comment: @ysrb - I want it to submit and do a postback (that will invoke the onbeforeunload method - I have updated the code to clarify that a bit.

Comment: Why use onbeforeunload at all?  Why can't you do what you want with just the click handler?

Comment: Yes, agree with gilly3. You can do the checking inside the click function.

Comment: Ahhh - I would love that solution if it would meet my requirements.  However I have a custom app inside SharePoint. I need to do a check if any links on the page are clicked, not just my click handler.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.. it ignore form submissions

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var warn_on_unload = "";
$('input:text,textarea').on('change', function () {
    warn_on_unload = "Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.";
    $("form").submit(function () {
        warn_on_unload = "";
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (warn_on_unload != '') {
            return warn_on_unload;
        }
    }
});
```

});